# Pass sub params in url http.get AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, url

I need to GET from a url of this pattern
`api/v1/album/:albumId/song/:songId/`

How do I pass these params in the url.

I tried using `params` in
`params: {
            albumId: 2,
            songId: 4
        }`

but the GET call was made to `api/v1/album/:albumId/song/:songId/?albumId=2&songId=4`
instead of
`api/v1/album/2/song/4/`

How can this be done without using string concatenation?

Comment: Consider using `$resource` instead of `$http`. `$resource` knows how to interpolate your URL pattern but `$http` does not.

Comment: Yup, I started working in that direction. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) service, `$resource` can make this work easier:

More info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Example code:

```
var Song = $resource('/api/v1/album/:albumId/song/:songId/',
                      {albumId: '@albumId', songId: '@songId'});

Song.get({albumId: 2, songId: 4}, function(song) {
    //returned song object

});

//or chaining with promise object
Song.get({albumId: 2, songId: 4})
    .$promise.then(function(song){
    //success handler
    $scope.selectedSong = song;
}, function() {
    //failure handler
});
```

There are more options depends on your requirement. Hope this can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

`Params: { .. }` are concatenated on the url as querystring which happened in your case. Simply construct your url having the parameter values included e.g.

```
var url = 'api/v1/album/1/song/2';
$http.get(url).then(function(){ .... });
```

Comment: Since the values of `albumId` and `songId` depend on the user's input, would using string concatenation be a secure option? Is there any way apart from using string concatenation?

Comment: There is no difference between the Params approach vs the one i've posted it is still getting the input from the user, if you want it to be secured then validate first the ids before calling get.